# Manage the scrolling of just one element in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

So, I have a ScrollView which has cards on it. ScrollView must be paging enabled.

The goal is that the user must be able to scroll it, even if it has only one card. Since i am having the frame of ScrollView of exactly the same width and height as a picture of a card, i decided to increase the width of a ScrollView.contentSize and add one point to it.

It turns out to be working fine, but it glitches a bit - when i drag the card to the left, and then grab it again it moves to right a little bit (i guess, for the value of that one point). If i increase the contentSize, the shift increases too (for example, if the content size is increased by ten, the shift value is ten points too). It really irritates me a lot and I want to get rid of it.

Any advice on how to do that? Help is much appreciated.

UPD: I tried to manually re-center the card in the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating but that didn't help. My guess for now is that the problem can be solved by setting the content offset to the right value (because now it's (0,0)), but I can't figure out how to do it.

UPD2: Here is some code that i use for now:

```
calendarScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 334, 372)]; 
//The cards themselves are 334 points wide too
calendarScrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
calendarScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
calendarScrollView.bounces = YES;
calendarScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
calendarScrollView.delegate = self;

//This part is used in the cycle of creating the cards
for (...) {

...

if (onlyOneCard) {
  calendarScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(335, 372);
  onlyOneCard = 0;
} else {
  calendarScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(334+offsetInScrollView, 372); //offsetInScrollView is increased by 334 by every end of the iteration of the cycle
}

...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the scrollview's **bounces** property to TRUE.

It will then always bounce back if you've gone beyond the bounds of the scroll view. :)

Comment: how about the bounces property?

Comment: Set it to be TRUE too, didn't help either.

Comment: perhaps you could post some code? I am happy to help with a bit more information.

Comment: I would first remove that extra pixel.. it's a hack and it you say it doesn't work. Next, if you created the view completely in code, I can't seem to figure out the problem. Paging enabled causes the subviews to snap. Yours doesn't seem to be doing that. Bounces causes you to swipe further out of the ContentSize and for it to bounce back. Also doesn't seem to be working. Are you working with IB also? If yes, are you sure everything is properly linked together?

Comment: All the views are created in code. I am using no IB anywhere.

I found the solution:

calendarScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(335, 372);
calendarScrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
calendarScrollView.bounces = YES;

This works totally fine. Thanks a lot for reminding me of bounces property. I'll mark your answer as right.